# Can variables be used to rewrite a Custom Post Type permalink?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Is it possible to use a variable to rewrite a Custom Post Type permalink FROM wp_terms -> slug?

> **WPDB:** wp_terms -> slug = healthy-living

**A1) Current Custom Post Type args:**

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'issues/resources' ),
```

**A2) Current Permalink (works great!):**

```
http://localhost/issues/resources/title-of-resource.html
```

**B1) Desired Custom Post Type args (is this possible?):**

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'issues/$WP_TERM_SLUG_VAR/resources' ),
```

**B2) Desired Permalink:**

```
http://localhost/issues/healthy-living/resources/title-of-resource.html
```

If you have any suggestions, your time is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

filter "pre_post_link" to change the permalink rule, the first attribute is the rule set to the administrator and the second is the element which is to form the link

```
function my_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
  // filtered by post_type, returns the format permalink
  if( $post->post_type != 'book' ) return '/bookis_custom/%postname%';
  return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'my_pre_post_link', 9, 3 );
```

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than just posting a block of code.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I can not write English, but Wordpress XD

Comment: We understand that English may not be the native language for all of our users-- I think non-English is a pretty high percentage actually--, but we still want a "human" explanation rather than just code and Stack policy is "English". Your grammar, spelling, etc. can be, and probably will be, cleaned up by other users.